# Remove column from MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I am pulling a list of names from the Database based on number of customers:

```
SELECT Name, count(CustName) FROM orders GROUP BY Name;
```

It returns:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Name   | count(CustName) |
+--------+-----------------+
| Abel   |               3 |
| Jones  |               2 |
| Murphy |               1 |
| Zenith |               1 |
+--------+-----------------+
```

How do I now, ONLY list Names that have count(CustNames) >= 2? I do not want to see the count(CustName) column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      Name
FROM orders 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING count(CustName) >= 2;
```